# Use opengl-command from different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opengl

I have two threads: One main-thread (opengl) for 3d-rendering and one thread for logic. How should I connect the threads if I want to create a box-mesh in the rendering thread, if the order comes from the logic-thread?

In this case the logic-thread would use opengl-commands, which is not possible because every opengl-command should only be exectued in the main-thread. I know that I can not share opengl context over different threads (which seems to be a bad idea), so how should I solve this problem? Do there exist some general purpose design pattern or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement a draw commands queue. Each draw command contains whatever is needed to make the required OpenGL calls. Each frame the rendering thread empties the current queue and processes the commands. Any other thread prepares its own commands and enqueues them at any time to the queue for the next frame.

Very primitive draw commands can be implemented as a class hierarchy with virtual `Draw` method. Of course this is not a small change at all but modern engines adopt this approach, of course much more advanced version of it. It can be efficient if the subsystems which submitted their command objects re-use them in the next frame, including their buffers. So each submodule constantly prepares and updates the draw command but submits it only when it should be rendered based on some logic.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to approach this. One is to implement a command queue with the logic thread being a command producer and the rendering thread the consumer.

Another approach is to make use of an auxiliary OpenGL context, which is setup to share the primary OpenGL context data. You can have both contexts made current at the same time in different threads. And for OpenGL-3.x core onward, you can make current a context without a drawable. You can then use the auxiliary context to load new data, map buffers and so on.